# sh script doesn't add ssh key to ssh-agent (windows git bash)

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh, push

I am using Github for Windows on Windows 7. I have a bash script to add the ssh-key to my ssh-agent. I have setup a ssh remote repo.

**add_key.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd ../ssh/
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add id.rsa
cd ../htdocs/
```

Execute command-

```
./add_key.sh
```

It returns

```
Agent pid 5548
Identity added: id.rsa (id.rsa)
```

When I git push origin master, it fails.
But when I manually cd in the ssh directory, and run the same ssh-related commands and cd back to my directory htdocs and git push to origin master, it works.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Where are you running the `git push` from? Some other shell session? Does that shell-session have the `ssh-agent` environment options set correctly?

Comment: Same shell session. I have not setup any ssh-agent env options. I am running the git push from inside the repo folder (htdocs).

Comment: Are you using `.`/`source` to run that "script" or are you using `./script.sh`? Because the latter means your `git push` cannot be in the same session as that script runs in its own shell session.

Comment: I removed the .sh extension and ran again, but it doesn't work. So does the executable always creates a separate session?

Comment: The extension doesn't matter. How you run it does. Running a script as `/path/to/script.sh` starts a new shell. Using `. /path/to/script.sh` uses the current shell.

Comment: So I am executing as ./add_key . That should be in the same shell. So then?

Comment: No, that's `/path/to/script.sh`. Your path just happens to be `./`. You want `. add_key` or `. ./add_key`. Note the space.

Comment: Great! Removing the back-slash and inserting a space worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75972/discussion-between-goelakash-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that your script is running in its own shell session because you are running `./add_key.sh`.

This means that the variables set by `eval $(ssh-agent)` are not living beyond that shell session so the parent session doesn't have them and cannot use the agent (also you might be spawning a new agent each time you run the script).

The fix for this is to run that "script" in the current session by dot-sourcing the script instead of running it as an external script.

That is you want to use `. add_key.sh`.